# Significant voltage drop across IGBT

Tags: transistors, mosfet-driver, igbt, wireless-charging

I'm using an IGBT in a wireless charger circuit as a swtich to send 'pulses' of power across the gap. I have 14V coming from the mosfet driver and I can see around 5v on the collector. I have the emitter connected to ground and the gate connected to the output of the mosfet driver.

Has anyone any idea why I'd be losing 9v across it??

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using an IGBT... this is MOSFET territory. There is an annoying characteristic with igbts at low blocking voltage

Comment: What is the frequency of operation? You may want to use a MOSFET, especially since your voltage is so low. What kind of current are you looking at? I bet the IV losses will also be less with a MOSFET.

Comment: Its at 250kHz im sending across 3 to 8w of power an IGBT gives me the switching speed with all the benifits of a BJT. Using a power pack at the moments so 14v around 0.5A Its this specific one if your intrested http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/149/FGH40T100SMD-889024.pdf